# PHP json_encode returns false

Tags: sql

I am trying to get these data from the DB and I am stuck at this case in the query.

I am trying to do so:

```
(case when e.email = NULL then c.user  end) as email
```

Basically what I want to do is in case e.email turns NULL, I want the c.user to be the e-mail. It is not working and I am new to this "advanced sql".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `coalesce`, which will return the first non-null argument:

```
coalesce(e.email, c.user) as email
```

By the way, in SQL `NULL = NULL` returns `NULL`. You have to use `IS` for the comparison operator when checking if a value is null i.e. `e.email IS NULL` as opposed to `e.email = NULL`